# Getting Result From JSON, JQUERY Not functioning

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have some problem. I have created some app that consuming JSON array.

The syntax is using Jquery 1.9

The logic is : getting values from textbox (valobj variable below) then write to toprightsec div area.

```
$("#btnsearch").click(function() {
        valobj = $('#search_box').val();
        $.getJSON("search.php", { q : valobj }, function(data,result){
            //show result from database
            $('toprightsec').append("Title" + data.title)
                            .append("Intro" + data.intro_text);
            //end show result
        }, JSON);
    });
```

JSON array is from PHP result. some example

```
{"content":[{"title":"Test Post 100","intro_text":"Intro Test"}]}
```

But, it's not working. any helps?

thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

```
$("#btnsearch").click(function() {
    valobj = $('#search_box').val();
    $.getJSON("search.php", { q : valobj }, function(data,result){
        //show result from database
        $('.toprightsec').append("Title" + data.content[0].title)
                        .append("Intro" + data.content[0].intro_text);
        console.log(data)
        //end show result
    }, JSON);
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnsearch").click(function() {
    valobj = $('#search_box').val();
    $.getJSON("search.php", { q : valobj }, function(data,result){
        //show result from database
        $.each(data.content, function() {
            $('.toprightsec').append("Title" + data.content[0].title)
                        .append("Intro" + data.content[0].intro_text);
        });

        //end show result
    }, JSON);
});
```

Comment: use `data.content[0].title` and so on

Comment: hi @x4rf41 it's not working. The section content still the same. nothing changed

Comment: Try using `console.log(data)` to look at the structure of the JSON in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
 $('.toprightsec').append("Title" + data.content[0].title)
                            .append("Intro" + data.content[0].intro_text);
```

instead of:

```
 $('toprightsec').append("Title" + data.title)
                            .append("Intro" + data.intro_text);
```

If `toprightsec` is id then use the # and if class then use the `.`. here you have not specify that.

Comment: maybe his selector is wrong too. what would this `$('toprightsec')` select ?

Comment: @x4rf41 I have mention about it in the answer. hope this will be understandable to OP.

Comment: hi @x4rf41 the toprightsec is a class. please see the update section

Comment: @randytan then use the `.` before the toprightsec and is there only one tag or more than one with this class name?

Comment: only one class: <td width="25px"><div class="toprightsec">Content for  class "toprightsec" Goes Here</div></td>

Comment: @randytan have you tried my answer. if yes then what you get?

Comment: aha, thanks @GauravVashishtha for answer, but it still showing only first array? coz of [0] how if i want to show all the array list?

Comment: @randytan you can use the `$.each` loop of jQuery. read it from here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: @GauravVashishtha hi, i have try to use function each, but the result is looping the array[0], how to make it dynamic array? thanks gaurav
pls see UPDATE 2 thanks

Comment: @randytan you need to pass the function(index,value){} arguments in each function. and alert them to check the values.

Comment: @gaurav, i think my second question is different, so i create new thread to make it clear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146122/getting-list-result-from-json-array

Answer (score 0):

You are using json array,so you have to access single array element and not whole array:

```
json_array.title //WRONG 
json_array[0].title //OK
```

**Try something like:**

```
$("#btnsearch").click(function() {
        valobj = $('#search_box').val();
        $.getJSON("search.php", { q : valobj }, function(data,result){
            //show result from database
            if (data.length){
                var _props = data.pop().content;
                $('toprightsec').append("Title" + _props.title)
                                .append("Intro" + _props.intro_text);
            }
            //end show result
        }, JSON);
    });
```

Comment: you are forgetting about the `content` array

Comment: there is another one :D `var _props = data.pop().content;` should be `var _props = data.content.pop();`