# Getting List Result From JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json

After getting the first row result from `JSON array`, I need to print the all result using `jquery` each method.

here's my syntax

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnsearch").click(function() {
    valobj = $('#search_box').val();
    $.getJSON("search.php", { q : valobj }, function(data,result){
        //show result from database
        $.each(data.content, function() {
            $('.toprightsec').append("Title" + data.content[0].title)
                        .append("Intro" + data.content[0].intro_text);
        });

        //end show result
    }, JSON);
});
```

The `data.content[0]` is showing the first row only with looping. But the data it self not changed. How to solve the `data.content[0]`.title, so the row is printed like in database?

**UPDATE**

After creating some tweak to my function, i have added new feature to show the result using list.

Here's the syntax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //function to get the result from user-input
    $("#btnsearch").click(function() {
        valobj = $('#search_box').val();
        $.getJSON("search.php", { q : valobj }, function(data,result){
            //show result from database
            $.each(data.content, function(index, value) {
                $("#divContent").show();
                var li = $("<li><a></a><br /><p></p></li>");
                $("#posting").append(li);
                    $("a",li).text(value.title);
                    $("p",li).text(value.intro_text);           
            });

            //end show result
        }, JSON);
    });
```

The question is, how i can reset the result from  if, we want to show based on another keyword, so the list is clear if user type new keywords? without refreshing the browser.

thank you.

**UPDATE 2**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    //function to get the result from user-input
    $("#btnsearch").click(function() {
        //clear the div
        $("#divContent").html("");

        valobj = $('#search_box').val();
        $.getJSON("search.php", { q : valobj }, function(data,result){
            //show result from database
            $.each(data.content, function(index, value) {
                $("#divContent").show();
                var li = $("<li><a></a><br /><p></p></li>");
                $("#posting").append(li);
                    $("a",li).text(value.title);
                    $("p",li).text(value.intro_text);           
            });  
            //end show result
        }, JSON);
    });
```

Comment: That's not how `$.each` method is supposed to be used, refer to it's documentation.

Comment: @undefined i see the syntax from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the each you can capture the element at the current iteration:

```
$.each(data.content, function(i, val) {
    $('.toprightsec')
        .append("Title" + val.title)
        .append("Intro" + val.intro_text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the $.each function there are two arguments. first one is index and second one is value.

Like this:

```
$.each(data.content, function(index,value) {
   alert(value);
}
```

and you can use them as a variables and in your case the each loop will be execute like this:

```
$.each(data.content, function(index, value) {
    $('.toprightsec')
        .append("Title" + value.title)
        .append("Intro" + value.intro_text);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but mrcode is write the first answer, i will mark the answer to his/her answer. Thank you for your support Gaurav!

Comment: @randytan no prob. as you wish. I just elaborate the answer. and the reason.

Comment: i have tweak the code so that it can show based on list. But how to make the div clear after new keyword was inserted without refreshing the browser?

Comment: use `$("#id").html("");` this will clear the contents of div.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how i implement the div clear? it makes the function against each other, so nothing shows up. please see the update 2 if you don't mind.

Comment: @randytan you are clearing the `divContent` and putting the content in `posting` div. it is not understandable to me. what you want to do?

Comment: the logic is when user clicks the button, the user clear the div area then add another value to the list. Or i need to remove the list only?